# R get item of list1 where its position in list 2 is 1

Tags: r, list

Say that I have two lists:

```
list1=c(item1,item2,item2,item4)

list2=c(1,0,0,1)
```

I want to extract from list1 items for-which position in list2 is '1'.

eg in our case:

item1 and item4.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `list1[list2 == 1]` will do that

Comment: list1[list2=="1"]

Answer (score 0):

You can use  for loop like

List_count = “a”

For (i in length(list2)) 
{

X<-Ifelse(list2[i] == 1, list1[i], “NA”)

List_count <- append(list_Count, x)

}

List_count <- list_count[-1]

List_count

Hope it will help you